# Workaround for latest Selenium unsupported "onload dialog"?

Tags: javascript, testing, selenium, selenium-rc

The Selenium Reference [documentation](http://release.seleniumhq.org/selenium-core/0.8.0/reference.html) says "Selenium does NOT support JavaScript alerts that are generated in a page's onload() event handler. In this case a visible dialog WILL be generated and Selenium will hang until someone manually clicks OK."

But how life goes - I happen to have an application that uses onload dialogs. I know of the "browserbot" workaround for previous versions but none of this works anymore for Selenium Webdrivers...

Has anybody tackled this one already?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. The limitation is only for Selenium RC (which has been oficially deprecated for like a year). Use Selenium `WebDriver`, if you can. It does not suffer from this limitation. If you use `WebDriver`, then [`driver.switchTo().alert()`](http://selenium.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/docs/api/java/org/openqa/selenium/Alert.html) should work as usual.
2. In Java, one can use ['Robot'](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/awt/Robot.html) for pressing <kbd>Enter</kbd> blindly. That way, I can't read the dialog's message, but at least can get rid of it.
3. In C#, there's [`SendKeys`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.sendkeys.aspx) class for the same thing.
4. You can't do anything in plain JavaScript, I think.

Comment: So, what's your language of choice and which Selenium product do you use?

Comment: Currently I'm using Selenium 1.8 to write the tests and will ecport them to C# NUnit.

Comment: Aha, Selenium IDE! I don't have the installation here, but if it can export to C# WebDriver, then the problem should be solvable by the switchTo().alert() solution above (just it was Java, not C#, but it's [almost the same](http://selenium.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/docs/api/dotnet/html/M_OpenQA_Selenium_IWebDriver_SwitchTo.htm)). Sooo. If you can, try it. If that doesn't work, since the IDE can only export to Selenium RC, the go for the [SendKeys class](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.sendkeys.aspx).

Comment: Yes IDE can export to c# Webdriver. Thanks